# How to align two TextViews within LinearLayout cell?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, textview, android-gridlayout

I have a vertical list (vertical LinearLayout). Within Each cell I have two EditText fields, next to each other. The first should be aligned to the left of the cell, the second aligned to the middle of the cell, basically resulting in two columns next to each other. I thought I used a two column GridLayout. To my surprise however, the second EditText is aligned to the right of the cell rather than the middle of the cell. What do I wrong?

```
    <GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
    android:columnCount="2" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sourceLanguage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="test1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#FF3366"
        android:textIsSelectable="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/targetLanguage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="test2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#993366"
        android:textIsSelectable="true" />

</GridLayout>
```

[image]
Almost there, but not quit... besides the second column is not exactly left-aligned.

Here is the desired result!!!

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use a `LinearLayout` and `weightSum`. I modified your code (see below). Note the added `weightSum` in the `LinearLayout`, the changed widths of the `TextViews` and the `layout_weights` of the `TextViews`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sourceLanguage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="test1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#FF3366"
        android:textIsSelectable="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/targetLanguage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="test2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#993366"
        android:textIsSelectable="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Shade, thanks for your answer. But now the second TextView is aligned not with 50%, but ca. 70% of the cell, see screen shot question.

Comment: @jhulst, yes, my post was edited and I didn't notice the gravity was changed. Edited it again and should be fine now.

Comment: Heehaa!, that worked (see screen_shot question), thanks a ton!